# How to make the anchor tag focused when the page is loaded

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a problem with my code. I have two anchors that show different content on the page when clicked. I also made them focus when clicked. But I don’t know how to make the current active anchor focused when the page loads for the first time.

I looked online for a solution, but none of them worked, so I’m hoping to get some help here!

Here is my code:

HTML

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="insandstu">
        <h1 class="insandstuh1">More than just books.</h1>
        <a class="insanchor" href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="showInstructors();">FOR INSTRUCTORS</a> <span> | </span>
        <a class="stuanchor" href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="showStudents();">FOR STUDENTS</a><br>
        <!-- FOR INSTRUCTORS -->
        <div id="ins-container">
            <p class="forins" id="forins1">LMS Integration</p>
            <p class="forins" id="forins2">Test banks</p>
            <p class="forins" id="forins3">Answer guides</p>
            <p class="forins" id="forins4">Powerpoint slides</p>
            <a class="forinsanchor" id="forinsanchor" href="">Explore now <img src="./greater-than.svg" alt="greater-than sign" height="12px" style="color: #0dc0dc;"></a>
        </div><br>
        <!-- FOR STUDENTS -->
        <div id="stu-container">
            <p class="forstu" id="forstu1">Highlighting</p>
            <p class="forstu" id="forstu2">Note-taking</p>
            <p class="forstu" id="forstu3">Multiple book formats</p>
            <p class="forstu" id="forstu4">Free online</p>
            <a class="forstuanchor" id="forstuanchor" href="">Explore now <img src="./greater-than.svg" alt="greater-than sign" height="12px" style="color: #0dc0dc;"></a>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Css

```
.hidden {
    display: none;
}
.insandstu {
    background-color: white;
    padding: 40px 80px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.insandstuh1 {
    font-size: 30px;
}

.insanchor {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #4c7db8;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.insanchor:focus {
    color: black;
    border-bottom: 2px solid black;
}
.stuanchor {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #4c7db8;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.stuanchor:focus {
    color: black;
    border-bottom: 2px solid black;
}
/* For Instructor part */
#ins-container {
    padding-top: 26px;
}
.forins {
    padding: 20px;
    font-weight: bold;
    display: inline-block;
    
}

#forins1 {
    border-left: 4px solid #0dc0dc;
    border-radius: 2px;
    width: 120px;
}

#forins2 {
    border-left: 4px solid #fdbd3e;
    border-radius: 2px;
    width: 90px;
}

#forins3 {
    border-left: 4px solid #0c9372;
    border-radius: 2px;
    width: 100px;
}

#forins4 {
    border-left: 4px solid #c22032;
    border-radius: 2px;
    width: 130px;
}

#forinsanchor {
    border-left: 4px solid transparent;
    border-image: linear-gradient(0deg, #F36B32, #002469, #C02336, #FABC4D, #25C0DA) 4;
    border-radius: 2px;
    font-weight: bold;
    box-shadow: 0 0.2rem 0.4rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    padding: 25px 50px 20px 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #026aa1;
}

/* For Student part */
#stu-container {
    display: none;
}
.forstu {
    padding: 20px;
    font-weight: bold;
    display: inline-block;
}
#forstu1 {
    border-left: 4px solid #0dc0dc;
    border-radius: 2px;
    width: 120px;
}

#forstu2 {
    border-left: 4px solid #fdbd3e;
    border-radius: 2px;
    width: 90px;
}

#forstu3 {
    border-left: 4px solid #0c9372;
    border-radius: 2px;
    width: 100px;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    position: relative;
    top: 7.3px;
}

#forstu4 {
    border-left: 4px solid #c22032;
    border-radius: 2px;
    width: 130px;
}

#forstuanchor {
    border-left: 4px solid transparent;
    border-image: linear-gradient(0deg, #F36B32, #002469, #C02336, #FABC4D, #25C0DA) 4;
    border-radius: 2px;
    font-weight: bold;
    box-shadow: 0 0.2rem 0.4rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    padding: 25px 50px 20px 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #026aa1;
}
```

JavaScript

```
function showInstructors() {
    // Get the rows by their id
    let instructorsRow = document.getElementById("ins-container");
    let studentsRow = document.getElementById("stu-container");
    // Remove the hidden class from the instructors row
    instructorsRow.classList.remove("hidden");
    studentsRow.style.display = "none";

    // Add the hidden class to the students row
    studentsRow.classList.add("hidden");
  }

  function showStudents() {
    // Get the rows by their id
    let instructorsRow = document.getElementById("ins-container");
    let studentsRow = document.getElementById("stu-container");

    // Remove the hidden class from the students row
    studentsRow.classList.remove("hidden");
    studentsRow.style.display = "block";

    // Add the hidden class to the instructors row
    instructorsRow.classList.add("hidden");
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to focus elements, you can use the `focus` method in your JavaScript functions: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/focus .

But you should also note that might have some accessibility concerns in your code:

1. You should prefer using buttons, not anchors, for this use-case. Anchors should be for links.
2. It looks like what you're really building here is tabs. In that case, consider having a look at https://daily-dev-tips.com/posts/a11y-101-tabs